# Как зашифровать пароль используя md5, перед записью в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["register"])){


if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];



    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows==0)
    {
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
            (full_name, email, username,password) 
            VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);


    if($result){
     $message = "Учетная Запись Успешно Создана";
    } else {
     $message = "Не удалось вставить данные!";
    }

    } else {
     $message = "Это имя пользователя уже существует! Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз!";
    }

} else {
     $message = "Заполните все поля!";
}
}
?>


<?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"error\">" . "MESSAGE: ". $message . "</p>";} ?>

<div class="container mregister">
            <div id="login">
    <h1>Регистрация</h1>
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="register.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Имя<br />
        <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" class="input" size="32" value=""  /></label>
    </p>


    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Email<br />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" value="" size="32" /></label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Имя пользователя<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Пароль<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="32" /></label>
    </p>    


        <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="button" value="Регистрация" />
    </p>

    <p class="regtext">Если есть аккаунт то? <a href="index.php" >Войти</a>!</p>
</form>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [BcryptHasher.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b4c0ef18e7c27bcbe125d5a3750e642544f7436d/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L36)

Comment: А смысл его шифровать, если тут сплошные дыры...

Comment: Использование слов md5 и пароль в одном предложении в 2019 году это сразу диагноз

Comment: https://xkcd.ru/i/327_v1.png

Comment: стоковый драйвер mysql(у нас 95ый год?)... нету даже эскейп стринга  для экранизации тех же самых скобочек в запросах sql(элементарная защита от поломки запросов sql)... (а вообще лучше с prepared запросами иметь дело :D)

Answer (score 2):

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
$pass = md5($password);
```